# Is Masterclass worth it for a middle-grade author?

Tags: fiction, technique, novel, education, middle-grade

I already read Larry Brooks' very useful book "Story Engineering", and Mary Kole's Writing Irresistible Kidlit. Now I have finished and revised my first middle-grade (MG) novel a few times.

Before starting another book and while waiting for the query responses, I thought about signing up on the Masterclass website. Besides a class from R.L. Stine, they mainly have classes from adult novel authors such as James Patterson.

Do you think the classes would still be useful for me, or are there other, better resources you can recommend? Maybe also something specifically for writing voice/style, to achieve a better flow that sucks you into the story.

Comment: have you checked out https://writingexcuses.com/ ?

Comment: I've heard mixed reviews for the Masterclass courses-- some very enthusiastic; some finding them disappointing, basic, or more inspiration and hand-waving than practical advice. I haven't heard anything about the R.L. Stine course specifically.

Comment: I have the masterclass from Patterson, but I wasn't very impressed. It felt more like an interview with Patterson on writing tips rather than an actual course. It wasn't constructed like a course at all. I've only bought the one course, but if it is indicative of them all, I would suggest you put your money elsewhere. I would recommend Udemy if you're into online courses, or the thousands of writing books out there. Anything from Writer's Digest is generally going to be well worth the money in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

There's a MasterClass from Judy Blume on creating stories for kids which might be useful to you as well as R. L. Stine's class.